# iPhone - How to find NSURLConnection started or not?

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection

There's a delegate in NSURLConnection `"- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection"`

This will be called when the connection finishes. 
But is there any delegate or way to know when the connection has started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the NSURLConnection delegate method `connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:`. It will be called once when the connection starts, but be warned that it will be called again for every redirect response (if there are any).

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
```

can be used.

Comment: This delegate will be called when the app receives first response from server and not when the connection is initiated. If due to any reason, the first response from server is delayed, I won't be showing the indicator till it first response is received. So, this is not appropriate delegate method.

Comment: show the indicator just after you have called the nsurlconnection.